# What does (Preferred), (Tentative) and (Duplicate) mean against an IPv4 Address with ipconfig

Tags: windows, networking, subnet, ipv4

I have been tinkering with subnets and have noticed the above as annotations to the `IPv4` line of `ipconfig`.

> IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.1.241(Tentative)
>
> IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.1.8(Preferred)

What do they mean?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Preferred is what your client will ask the DHCP server for when it gets/renews the lease, but tentative is what it got in the response. Someone else probably has a lease on the preferred address. Duplicate is what it says when windows detects an IP address conflict (and then probably switches to another address).

To manually release and renew now:

```
ipconfig /release
ipconfig /renew
```